# Angularjs app using autocomplete.js and reading from multiple Algolia sources not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, algolia

I'm trying to implement autocomplete functionality using AngularJS and Algolia's Autocomplete.js with two sources (indexes) from Algolia.

The second source autocomplete works fine, but the address autocomplete only works for the first letter/number typed. As you type the second character, the address listings disappear. If I swap the two sources, the address works fine, and the zipcode only works for the first letter/number.

Additionally, when doing a search, the `console.log(address);` displays the proper address that's being searched for, it's just not displaying in the autocomplete results.

Here's a gif of it in action:
http://d.pr/i/2GCE

```
$scope.getDatasets = function() {
return [{
  source: algolia.sources.hits(settings.replica, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
  displayKey: 'address',
  name: 'address',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {

       var address = '<span class="address">' + suggestion._highlightResult.address.value;

       if(suggestion.aptmnt) {
        address += ', Unit ' +suggestion.aptmnt + '</span> | ';
       } else {
        address +='</span> | '; 
       }

       address += '<span>' + suggestion.totbdrms + ' beds </span> | ' +
        '<span>' + suggestion.totbaths + ' bath asdf </span> | ' +
        ' <span> $' + cleanPrice(suggestion.price) + '</span>';
        console.log(address);
        return address;
    }
  }
},{
  source: algolia.sources.hits(settings.zipcode, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
  displayKey: 'zipcode',
  name: 'zipcode',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {
       var zipcode = '<span class="zipcode">' + suggestion.zipcode + '</span>';
        return zipcode;
    }
  }
}]
};
```

I'm using

```
jquery - v1.12.4
angularjs - 1.6.1
algoliasearch.angular.min.js - v3
algoliasearch.helper.min.js - v2.18.0
autocomplete.angular.min.js - v0.28.1
angular-ui-router.js - v0.4.2
```

Comment: Do you have a live example of your problem?

Comment: I can't share it publicly. Any other way I can send to you?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a workaround. I never could get the Angular version of this autocomplete to work. Additionally, when I `console.log(o);` the constructor function `function Dataset(o) {}` inside autocomplete.angular.js, it was logging it out twice. Not sure if that is the issue...but the normal autocomplete.js isn't logging that out twice.

Since swapping over to autocomplete.j, the autocomplete has been working great. Here's the code I'm using:

```
autocomplete('#quicksearch', { hint: false, debug: true, openOnFocus: true }, [
{
  source: autocomplete.sources.hits(settings.replica, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
  displayKey: 'address',
  name: 'address',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {

       var address = '<span class="address">' + suggestion._highlightResult.address.value;

       if(suggestion.aptmnt) {
        address += ', Unit ' +suggestion.aptmnt + '</span> | ';
       } else {
        address +='</span> | '; 
       }

       address += '<span>' + suggestion.totbdrms + ' beds </span> | ' +
        '<span>' + suggestion.totbaths + ' bath </span> | ' +
        ' <span> $' + suggestion.price + '</span>';
        return address;
    }
  }
},{
  source: autocomplete.sources.hits(settings.zipcode, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
  displayKey: 'zipcode',
  name: 'zipcode',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {
       var zipcode = '<span class="zipcode">' + suggestion.zipcode + '</span>';
        return zipcode;
    }
  }
}

]);
```